# create private/public key on device

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, hyperledger, blockchain, csr

I'm using hyperledger and I would understand if is possible to create private and public key directly on the device.

The applicative runs on the device might be on browser or on ionic framework.

The alternative could be to generate it on a server, with specific endpoint, and send it to a device. I think this last option is not very correct, right ?

Please, let me know.
Tnx

Comment: "I'm using hyperledger" says nothing. Which Hyperledger blockchain are you using? (Fabric, Sawtooth, etc)